# Is there a way to know when fscanf reads a whitespace or a new line?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to know if there is a way to know when fscanf reads a whitespace or a new line.

Example: 
formatting asking words italic
links returns

As fscanf read a string till it meets a newline or a whitespace(using %s), it'll read formatting and the space after it and before a. The thing is, is there a way to know that it read a space? And after it entered the second line is there is a way to know that it read a carriage return?

Comment: The answer is no. If you want to know such things, you will have to parse the input yourself.

Comment: Instead of doing that, just use `getline` or `fgets` to get a single line of input, then parse the line with `sscanf` or `atoi` as appropriate.

Comment: that is what i thought, i'd chose to take that lead and parse the whole line, but before start it i decided to look if there was a easier or simpler way, thanks Jim Balter and nneonneo.

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct fscanf to read whitespace into your variable instead of reading and discarding whitespace.  Use something like `[ \n\r\t]*` but you need to include more characters in that expression.  Depending on the locale and some features of the runtime character set, you might want to write a separate function to compute the appropriate format string once before using it.

If you need to distinguish \n from other kinds of whitespace, you have your variable containing the whitespace that you just finished reading.  You might want to count all of the \n characters in it, depending on your needs.